# AngularJS & CodeIgniter Routing refresh page error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-routing

Evening,

I'm currently practicing single page application using AngularJS and CodeIgniter, all the routing seems works perfectly when i clicked the navigation. And this is what it looks like before i refresh (f5) the page.

[image: Before refresh page]

And this is what it looks like after refreshing the page.

[image: After refresh page]

HTML Page script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="pracApp">
<head>
<base href="/prac/">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Test</title>
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen, projection">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" media="screen, projection">
</head>

<body ng-controller="homeController">
<!-- <div ng-controller="navigation" ng-include="navigation()"></div> -->
<nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/angular/angular-loader.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/app/controller.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>',
    site_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my app.js script

```
var pracApp = angular.module('pracApp', ['ngRoute']);

pracApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : base_url + 'home',
            controller  : 'homeController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : base_url + 'about',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : base_url + 'contact',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });


});


// pracApp.controller('navigation', function($scope) {
//  $scope.navigation = function() {
//      return base_url + 'partials/navigation';
//  };
// });

pracApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {
// $scope.message = "This is home controller";
});

pracApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
// $scope.message = "This is about controller";
});

pracApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
// $scope.message = "This is contact controller";
});
```

What I need is how to prevent the error (according to image 2).

Comment: need to configure server when you use `html5Mode` .. see $location docs

Comment: is `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` not enough? i already did that one on my config

Comment: No... that is only for angular to manage the client side routing. Server doesn't know anything about the new virtual directories you are using. Without html5Mode there is a hash in url that has no impact on server

Comment: Try this one http://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg/preview

Comment: @PareshGami i'm using that resource to start my practice, but i've modified it a bit. because it doesn't use $locationProvider.

Comment: @charlietfl do you have some example that i can use for my influence? it would be great if you have one :)

Comment: use htaccess to point to entry point of your angular app. Beware of the SEO implications also. It is not hard to find lots of information about this on the web